# What's the iOS DJI Go app custom URL scheme?

Tags: ios, url-scheme, dji-sdk

I found that `djivideo://` is one custom url which I can use from safari to open the iOS DJI Go app. Is there any other custom url like that?

What all parameters can I pass with that URL?

Can I set the drone destination point directly to an address?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend creating custom mobile app using [Mobile SDK](https://developer.dji.com/mobile-sdk/) as opposed to hack into DJI Go custom URLs. The custom URLs may or may not do what you intend to do. There are plenty of sample apps for Mobile SDK that will get you started right away. [Link](https://developer.dji.com/mobile-sdk/documentation/ios-tutorials/index.html) here.

Answer (score 0):

From [the official DJI developer site](https://developer.dji.com/mobile-sdk/documentation/application-development-workflow/workflow-run.html), the only custom URL schemes they support 3rd party developers using seem to be:

> Redirect to DJI Go 4 App : Use URL scheme "djiVideoNew://"
>
> Redirect to DJI Go App : Use URL scheme "djiVideo://"

If you want to reverse engineer an app's custom URL schemes, you can look at its Info.plist file, which lists them. This is easiest on a jailbroken device, where you can browse the whole filesystem.

Looking at a recent (but not current) version of DJI Go **4**, I see in Info.plist:

```xml
<key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
    <array>
      <dict>
        <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
        <string>Editor</string>
        <key>CFBundleURLName</key>
        <string>com.dji.go</string>
        <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
        <array>
          <string>djiVideoNew</string>
        </array>
      </dict>
```

But, there are also some other URL schemes, likely for supporting features of 3rd-party libraries DJI uses. But, I also see these:

```xml
  <dict>
    <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
    <string>Editor</string>
    <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
    <array>
      <string>djialipay916787060</string>
    </array>
  </dict>
  <dict>
    <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
    <string>Editor</string>
    <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
    <array>
      <string>djiLive4</string>
    </array>
  </dict>
```

Of course, knowing the scheme name alone tells you nothing about the URL parameters they may take. These are often completely undocumented, and can change at any time. You could try using a disassembler/decompiler to inspect the app (advanced topic). Or, with the custom URL scheme name in hand, simply start doing google searches to see if anyone else has reverse engineered or documented their use.